# How can a gRPC Server application written in .NET Core 3.0 be hosted?

Tags: azure, .net-core, grpc, cloud-hosting

With the release of .NET Core 3.0, the latest version of visual studio offers the gRPC Service template to create this type of service. 
Does anyone have idea what are my choice to host this kind of service (written in .Net Core 3.0) on the web? 
Does Azure have a solution to this?

Comment: Same as you host any other ASP.NET Core app.

Comment: @davidg except for [this](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/9020)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a kubernetes cluster on Azure and deploy your application on it. Azure App Services doesn't support gRPC. If you want to learn how you can create your first service in gRPC follow this article:
[gRPC service in .Net Core](https://medium.com/@dewanwaqas/goodbye-http-now-we-have-grpc-a-better-and-faster-way-of-client-server-communication-in-net-core-83c251a4db89)